# Change directory in a startup script debian

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command

I am running a debian VM Instance using GCP Compute Engine and I have added a automation script to be executed on startup.

There are few tools which will be downloaded on startup. Only issue is, everything is getting downloaded in / directory.

I need to download everything in $HOME directory.

Different ways I have tried

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
cd $HOME
mkdir $HOME/test
cd $HOME/test 
apt install wget -y
wget https://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk11/ri/openjdk-11+28_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
```

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
source $HOME
mkdir $HOME/something
```

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
cd $HOME
mkdir $HOME/something 
exec bash
```

Still it is downloaded in / directory. What else can be done here?

Comment: `source $HOME` ? what does it do? In any case use the debug flag `-x` to run your scirpt. either put it after the shebang `set -x` or run your script whit `bash -x ./myscript`

Comment: I just tried using source, i have tried with set -x as well

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to make 2 things : install wget package and download another one.

Why don't you tried to install wget manually ?

```
apt-get install wget
```

You have then to store the full path for your script, and download the package needed it it. Try this :

```
#!/bin/bash
homePath=$HOME
mkdir $HOME/test
wget https://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk11/ri/openjdk-11+28_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz -P $homePath/test/
```

Comment: lets say instead of download i want to do mkdir in $HOME directory, it doesnt work

Comment: Please share with us your full code if you want to be helped. I have answered with information provided

Comment: I have modified the question to include the code

Comment: Before to try to help you more about your issue, please answer the following question : what is the error message / error code ? Do you have sudo right with this user ? Do you have acces / read / write privilege to your folder ?

Comment: i am not getting any error, if i am running the script after getting in the terminal, it works fine, but i am using this as a startup script. Yes, I am a root user

Comment: Can you give me the ouput of #HOME ?

Comment: /home/myusername

Comment: Please check my edit and tell me if it works now.

Comment: it doesn't work, test directory gets created in / directory

Comment: Between line 2 and line 3, add "echo $homePath" to verify if HOME environnement variable works well.